# How Linux Host can access guest's sharing network on Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have Windows 7 as a guest with Ubuntu Host, the windows got an Internet access via USB modem which is not available for Linux.

I have enabled sharing on Windows network and assigned an IP, netmask and getway to that network and to `vboxnet0`, the ping was successful but I've got a one problem.

How Ubuntu can detect the guest's network so it can connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change **default gw**?

E.g.

Your host `vboxnet0` have ip address `192.168.0.1`.

Your Windows(guest) have ip address `192.168.0.2`.

Try to set default gateway on the host(Ubuntu) to `192.168.0.2`.

```
# route add default gw 192.168.0.2
```